# Is Umbridge’s Patronus that of a cat Inferius?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, when Umbridge was Head of the Muggle-born registration commission, we see her Patronus, which is the same as McGonagall’s, a cat.

However, we can clearly see the skeletal features in it, and Umbridge’s HP Wiki used to say that “it resembled more of a reanimated cat corpse,” but that got deleted.

So is the Patronus a cat Inferius?

You can clearly see the skeletal features in this picture.

[image: Capture from the Deathly Hallows movie of a skeletal, glowing cat Patronus]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Umbridge’s Patronus is not an Inferius.

In the book, Umbridge’s Patronus is described as a long-haired cat. There is no mention of it being skeletal.

> “At the foot of the platform a bright silver, long-haired cat prowled up and down, up and down, and Harry realised that it was there to protect the prosecutors from the despair that emanated from the Dementors: that was for the accused to feel, not the accusers.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 13 (The Muggle-Born Registration Commission)*</sup></sub>

While it is not specified in the quote above, it is later made clear that the Patronus it refers to is Umbridge’s.

> “The moment he had passed the place where the Patronus cat patrolled he felt the change in temperature: it was warm and comfortable here. The Patronus, he was sure, was Umbridge’s, and it glowed brightly because she was so happy here, in her element, upholding the twisted laws she had helped to write.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 13 (The Muggle-Born Registration Commission)*</sup></sub>

At no point is it mentioned that Umbridge’s Patronus is supposed to be anything other than a normal cat.

#### However, it is dimmer than Harry’s Patronus.

Umbridge’s Patronus is, however, supposed to not be as bright as Harry’s. It’s possible that the cat’s appearance in the movie is meant to show that her Patronus is dimmer by comparison.

> “The silver stag soared from the tip of Harry’s wand and leapt towards the Dementors, which fell back and melted into the dark shadows again. The stag’s light, more powerful and more warming than the cat’s protection, filled the whole dungeon as it cantered round and round the room.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 13 (The Muggle-Born Registration Commission)*</sup></sub>

The “skeletal” appearance of the cat may be caused by it being shown as dimmer.